# Automatically define fields when parsing XMLs with logstash

Tags: xml, logstash

Is there any way in logstash to define fields automatically based on the XML contents when parsing an XML file with logstash's XML filter?

For example, let's say I have the following XML (copied from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I would like to parse it with logstash where logstash automatically defines for example a field called bookstore.book.title with the value "Everyday Italian" and a field called bookstore.book.title.lang with the value "en" and so on without having to define all of this manually (using xpath). The problem is that I'm trying to parse various XML files with different and complicated structures so defining a seperate structure for each file is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Logstash natively breaks down the attributes of the xml file (so what I needed is actually supported by logstash out of the box). The problem was that in my xml files, the end of an xml attribute (e.g. `</book>`) was in a seperate line so for logstash the attribute `<book>` was "broken" and this was causing an xml parse failure. To resolve the problem I needed to add a multiline codec to the input so that each attribute that needs to be parsed is located completely in one single line.